# OSX Lion - any way to TAG emails for filing?

Tags: apple-mail, osx-lion

Title says it all.  I didn't see that.  I don't know if this is a programming question, since there may be a way to do it built in.  If not, any programmers know how to do this?

Managing email ideally by archiving to one single folder.  But I need tags to consistently ensure if I have to search for something in a particular category it is there.

E.g., someone sends an email.  I read it.  I tag it. I archive it.

Comment: What is this I don't even

Comment: I think we need some more specificity here: how are you managing your email?

Comment: This forum is kind of dead.

Comment: It's pre-release software very few (sane) people already use in production. What do you expect?

Comment: I expect way too much, but otherwise life is boring.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a commercial app for $30 will do the trick:
http://support.indev.ca/discussions/questions/228-lion-mailtags

Looks pretty useful too.

Comment: I used it and with a minor upgrade it crashed, I had to uninstall it, and then I lost all my tags.  I won't go back to that, because I can't trust that once I've archived a message I can reliably know it has been tagged.